# How to group from MySQLi using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have table something like

[image]

I want to get ID of all records having same color code `group` but I don't how many colors are there in database means I don't want to use query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE group = Red` because I don't know color name. I was trying GROUP BY clause but didn't work. I want to perform different action on these records later on. Like I want to treat these group as one row. I tried following query it's not matching with table but something similar.

```
<?php

    $cquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(suid) AS count, rid, suid FROM response WHERE rsid = 1 GROUP BY suid");

    while($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cquery)) {

        echo $crow['rid'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $crow['suid'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Post what u tried?

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh updated bro.

Comment: Try: `SELECT COUNT(suid) AS count, rid, suid FROM response WHERE rsid = 1 GROUP BY suid, rid`

Comment: If it doesnt work for you, please update the question with some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$color = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM response WHERE rsid='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $color[$row['color']][] = $row['row_id'];
}
?>
```

you can try put all the result in array.
and implode the array to display the result.